# RTTI and DevExpress

Tags: devexpress, delphi-xe, rtti

I'm trying to get and set some property values on VCL components. Some are DevExpress and some are not.

I have wrtiten a small helper class:

```
type
  RttiHelper = class
  strict private
  public
    class function GetPropertyValue(const aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string): TValue; inline;
    class function GetPropertyValue2(const aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string): TValue; inline;    
    class procedure GetProperty(const aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string; var aRttiProperty: TRttiProperty); inline;
  end;

{ TRttiHelper }

class procedure RttiHelper.GetProperty(const aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string; var aRttiProperty: TRttiProperty);
var
  NextLevel: TObject;
begin
  aRttiProperty := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(aObject.ClassType).GetProperty(aPropertyName);

  if aRttiProperty = nil then // Try harder: Look after the property in next level
  begin
    aRttiProperty := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(aObject.ClassType).GetProperty(aSecondLevel);

    if aRttiProperty <> nil then
    begin
      NextLevel := aRttiProperty.GetValue(aObject).AsObject;
      if NextLevel = nil then
        exit;

      aRttiProperty := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(NextLevel.ClassType).GetProperty(aPropertyName);
    end;
  end;
end;

class function RttiHelper.GetPropertyValue(const aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string): TValue;
var
  RttiProperty: TRttiProperty;
  aInstance, Properties: TObject;
begin
  RttiProperty := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(aObject.ClassType).GetProperty(aPropertyName);
  aInstance := aObject;

  if RttiProperty = nil then // Try harder: Look after the property in next level
  begin
    RttiProperty := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(aObject.ClassType).GetProperty(aSecondLevel);

    if RttiProperty <> nil then
    begin
      Properties := RttiProperty.GetValue(aObject).AsObject;
      aInstance := Properties;

      if Properties = nil then
        exit(nil);

      RttiProperty := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(Properties.ClassType).GetProperty(aPropertyName);
    end;
  end;

  if RttiProperty = nil then // Nothing found
    exit(nil);

  Result := RttiProperty.GetValue(aInstance);
end;

class function RttiHelper.GetPropertyValue2(const aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string): TValue;
var
  RttiProperty: TRttiProperty;
begin
  RttiHelper.GetProperty(aObject, aPropertyName, aSecondLevel, RttiProperty);
  if RttiProperty <> nil then
    Result := RttiProperty.GetValue(aObject)
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

Preferable I would like to call the `GetProperty` method and then get or set the value but on DevExpress Components i dont get the correct result.

Here is how to reproduce:

Place a `TEdit` and `TcxTextEdit` on a form, and then write the following code:

```
  Edit1.Text := RttiHelper.GetPropertyValue2(Edit1, 'Color', 'Style').AsVariant;
  cxTextEdit1.Text := RttiHelper.GetPropertyValue2(cxTextEdit1, 'Color', 'Style').AsVariant;
```

While if I use this code it wotrks very well:

```
  Edit1.Text := RttiHelper.GetPropertyValue(Edit1, 'Color', 'Style').AsVariant;
  cxTextEdit1.Text := RttiHelper.GetPropertyValue(cxTextEdit1, 'Color', 'Style').AsVariant
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Create a variable (local or even better class var) of type `TRttiContext`. You don't ever need to call `TRttiContext.Create`. The designers of the type were drunk when they added that method.

Comment: As to the question, can you tell us what happens when you call `GetPropertyValue2`. In what way does it fail? What have you learnt from your debugging?

Comment: The Result is zero when I ask for the color of cxTextEdit1 no Exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line : `RttiProperty.GetValue(aObject)` I call GetValue on the the Original object, but it's not certainly that the property is placed on that object.

the property Color e.g is a very good example: On a TEdit it is placed on the "Main Object". You can write `Edit1.Color := clBlue;` but in a TcxTextEdit the Color property is placed on a style object, so you'll have to write: `cxTextEdit1.Style.Color := clBlue`. There for I need to call `RttiProperty.GetValue(aObject)` on the correct object.

In order for doing that I've cahanged the declaration of `GetProperty` from

```
class procedure GetProperty(const aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string; var aRttiProperty: TRttiProperty);
```

To:

```
class procedure GetProperty(var aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string; var aRttiProperty: TRttiProperty);
```

An the implementation changed to:

```
class procedure RttiHelper.GetProperty(var aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string; var aRttiProperty: TRttiProperty);
var
  NextLevel: TObject;
begin
  aRttiProperty := ctx.GetType(aObject.ClassType).GetProperty(aPropertyName);

  if aRttiProperty = nil then // Try harder: Look after the property in next level
  begin
    aRttiProperty := ctx.GetType(aObject.ClassType).GetProperty(aSecondLevel);

    if aRttiProperty <> nil then
    begin
      NextLevel := aRttiProperty.GetValue(aObject).AsObject;
      if NextLevel = nil then
        exit;
      aObject := NextLevel;
      aRttiProperty := ctx.GetType(NextLevel.ClassType).GetProperty(aPropertyName);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Then it works.

After a bit of cleanup this is my complpete helper:

```
unit RttiHelperU;

interface
uses
  RTTI;

type
  RttiHelper = class
  strict private
    class var ctx: TRttiContext;
  public
    class function GetProperty(var aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string): TRttiProperty;
    class function GetPropertyValue(aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string): TValue;
    class function SetPropertyValue(aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string; const aValue: TValue): boolean;
  end;

implementation

class function RttiHelper.GetProperty(var aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string): TRttiProperty;
var
  NextLevel: TObject;
begin
  Result := ctx.GetType(aObject.ClassType).GetProperty(aPropertyName);

  if Result = nil then // Try harder: Look after the property in next level
  begin
    Result := ctx.GetType(aObject.ClassType).GetProperty(aSecondLevel);

    if Result <> nil then
    begin
      NextLevel := Result.GetValue(aObject).AsObject;

      if NextLevel = nil then
        exit(nil);

      aObject := NextLevel;
      Result := ctx.GetType(NextLevel.ClassType).GetProperty(aPropertyName);
    end;
  end;
end;

class function RttiHelper.GetPropertyValue(aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string): TValue;
var
  RttiProperty: TRttiProperty;
begin
  RttiProperty := GetProperty(aObject, aPropertyName, aSecondLevel);

  if RttiProperty <> nil then
    Result := RttiProperty.GetValue(aObject)
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

class function RttiHelper.SetPropertyValue(aObject: TObject; const aPropertyName, aSecondLevel: string; const aValue: TValue): boolean;
var
  RttiProperty: TRttiProperty;
begin
  Result := False;
  RttiProperty := GetProperty(aObject, aPropertyName, aSecondLevel);

  if RttiProperty = nil then
    exit;

  try
    RttiProperty.SetValue(aObject, aValue);
    Result := true;
  except

  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: It worked fine for me for the `TEdit` control. The problem was with the DevEx control right? In which case, I guess I was wasting my time looking at `TEdit`.

Comment: Exactly. An the "NextLevel" object.

Comment: If I'd known that, it would have helped. As it was I just wasted lots of time investigating the wrong problem. I should make a rule not to spend time if the problem is not clear.

Comment: I have stated that all the time that the problem was related to DevExpress :D

Comment: You didn't state what went wrong.  Your question was vague.  I think you can learn from this.  Feel free to disagree with me.